# Remove rows with NaN columns if group size is larger than one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
    channel_id  user_agent_id  user_id_x  percents_normalized  user_id_y
0           1              1          1                  NaN        NaN    
1           1              2          1             0.734928        1.0
2           1              3          1             0.369057        1.0
3           2              1          2                  NaN        NaN
4           3              1          3                  NaN        NaN
5           3              5          3                  NaN        NaN
6           3             10          3                  NaN        NaN
7           4              2          4             0.734928        1.0
8           5              2          5             0.734928        1.0
```

I want to be able to group by channel_id and for each group remove the NaN records of each group with size larger than one and at least one non NaN value on `percents_normalized` column that is for channel_id's that is I want to remove Nan from channel_id 1. Channel 3 has size > 1 but all rows have NaN and channel id 2 has size 1.

Comment: What is your expected output from this input?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby.transform` to construct a boolean series for subsetting; The condition `((x.size==1) or x.isnull().all()) | x.notnull()` consists of a group level condition `(x.size==1) or x.isnull().all()` which gives `true` if the `id` has only one record or all of the records are null, and a record level condition `x.notnull()`, i.e. if the group level condition is not satisfied, keeps only non null values:

```
(df[df.groupby('channel_id').percents_normalized
      .transform(lambda x: ((x.size==1) or x.isnull().all()) | x.notnull()).astype(bool)])
```

[image]

Comment: Do I need the opening and closing parentheses? Do I use it as is or do I apply this to my initial dataframe?